# How do I change the width of an .input-group in Bootstrap, responsively?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I change the width of an `.input-group` to make it wider? I tried setting `width: 50%` but that puts a space between the input field and the button.

[image: bootstrap]

[image: new-width]

I also tried setting the width of the input field directly, but that also failed.

[image: bootstrap input 50%]

And setting it over 100%, which also failed.

[image: bootstrap input 110%]

It looks good if I set the width to 300px or 400px, but not on mobile.

Here is a Bootply http://www.bootply.com/HGr9b06Q1B

Comment: You've got an odd structure happening there. Include the full form in your bootply. Otherwise drop the `form-inline` class

Comment: I was trying to use Yii's [ActiveForm](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activeform.html) methods... boohoo... Dropping `form-inline`, manually coding the form, and setting width on `<form>` worked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to wrap it in bootstraps structure... like:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4"><!--width is set by this div -->

      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
        </span>
      </div><!-- /input-group -->

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See [this fork of your bootply](http://www.bootply.com/zT4WMfXHTP)

Oh, and try not to use the `<center>` element, it has been deprecated.

Answer (score -1):

i will recommend the easiest way to do that is style `.form-control` and another way can be you can nest your input inside `<div class='col-sm-3'> </div>`